# r.fill.dir blocked

Tags: grass-gis, dem, hydrology, depression-filling

I am trying to fille a DEM downloaded by Geobolivia http://geo.gob.bo/.

The r.fill.dir  module in QGIS/GRASS toolbox blocked few minutes after I launched it for the DEM. It is very strange as, for instace, r.watershed module works perfectly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you want to use r.fill.dir for? For watershed modelling please avoid sink filling, see the manual of r.watershed (it uses a least cost routing!) and also here: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences#Sink_filling:_why_not_needed_in_GRASS_GIS

Comment: I am working with QSWAT water delineation tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SAGA installed, try to use Fill Sinks as an alternative, and see if this tool can solve your problem. The tool can be accessed from `Processing Toolbox -> SAGA -> Terrain Analysis -> Hydrology -> Fill Sinks`.

Comment: It is blocked anyway, and so is the other Wang and Liu algorithm

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: The Qgis 2.14.3 - Essen

Comment: Working directly on SAGA GIS solved the problem for SAGA instructions!